# Show a partial without the layout.jade file

Tags: node.js, layout, express, pug

I'm using layout.jade as a template for all the partials. layout.jade includes a header, footer, sidebar etc, and the partials is what is shown in the body.

Now I've implemented a lightbox with iframe, to show one of the partials in. The problem is that I don't want the header, footer etc to be shown inside the lightbox, just the partial jade file.

Is there a way to exclude layout.jade in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here's how:

```
res.render('template', { layout: false /* ... other parameters */ });
```

See [Express docs on view rendering](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering). You can also specify a different layout.